# Cloning of Ubuntu with dd does not boot or have valid EFI files

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, bootloader

I've cloned a disk setup with ubuntu 20.04 in an encrypted partition, using dd to a larger NVME SSD.  However the BIOS no longer recognises any disk in the boot manager. The old disk will boot but only under CSM settings, on a windows computer. I've run the boot repair utility from both a live CD on the new disk however it hasn't solved this issue.
My EFI partition on the new clone doesn't contain any *.efi files and only has a System Volume Information folder which makes me think that perhaps a windows has overwritten my EFI partition on the original disk.
How can I recover this? My boot partition is still untouched.
The output from boot-repair utility run from a live-cd is located here (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cxMP5w7Tw6/)

Comment: "You need to be logged in to view this paste". By using paste.ubuntu.com you're crippling your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay recovered the system to normal operation...

firstly, the /boot/efi/EFI did not contain any binaries and that was the reason for the nvme drive not being detected by the bios. I think my Bios was only allowing UEFI mode and needed that folder to be populated.

I was able to recover and boot into my system using [SuperGrub2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/) This utility supports Ubuntu and Debian without the need for the EFI binaries to exist. It enabled a rebuild of the Grub2 menu options and allowed my system to boot fully. It also supports encrypted root partitions with LUKS, there is a menu option to enable this option, run that prior to letting the utility analyse the grub.cfg. This was far easier than chroot modifications.

The final steps, once logged in were to run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
sudo update-grub
```

**NB: These commands will restore the EFI directory and binaries iff the package `grub-efi-amd64` is installed**. install it with

```
sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64
```

and then run the two commands above.

As I had to install grub-efi-amd64, I'm not totally convinced that the disk image was setup to be run in UEFI mode initially.